# Is it possible to merge files into an obsolete branch in clearcase?

Tags: version-control, merge, clearcase, teradata

I have created a view under X branch. checked in the files successfully. But while merging the files I gave incorrect command and my files were merged into Y branch which is obsolete. How is it possible? It means I can merge files even to an Obsolete branch? Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If only the branch *type* is [locked obsolete](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm), that wouldn't prevent the branch (instance of a branch type) to be modified.

You can check the lock status with:

```
cleartool lslock <branch_name>@/vobs/avob
```

Or, for the brtype:

```
cleartool lslock brtype:<branch_name>@/vobs/avob
```

As [Ian W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598141/ian-w) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756126/is-it-possible-to-merge-files-into-an-obselete-branch-in-clearcase/33756675#comment55353575_33756675):

> If you are using UCM, there's a lock on the project and a locks on the streams. Pretty sure it's the lock on stream you want to have in place.

True: a lock on the UCM stream would lock the associated non-UCM branch.

Comment: I want to add more clarity to my question. Here X and Y are main branches from where I have created Sub branch(View). I merged the files to main branch which is obsolete.

Comment: @LalithaT sure: but first did you check what was locked? The branch or the brtype?

Comment: @LalithaT If the branhc is locked then no checkout or merge should be possible. Can you try and make a checkout manually, just to test?

Comment: If you are using UCM, there's a lock on the project and a locks on the streams. Pretty sure it's the lock on stream you want to have in place.

Comment: @IanW I agree. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.